# How to chessboard segment landsat pixel edges in python?

Tags: landsat, imagery, digital-image-processing, ecognition, image-classification

Does anyone know how to do a chessboard segmentation (in the same way that `ecognition` does) that will select all the edges of a Landsat pixel in python/a Jupyter notebook? Given that I can use the notebook to retrieve the imagery as a multi-band `xarray`, does anyone have a good recipe using `scikit-image` or similar to take the imagery array and run a chessboard segmentation on it, outputting the pixel edges as a shapefile? I want every pixel edge as opposed to areas of similarity.

I can do this in `ecognition`, and create a workflow. I'm looking for a python equivalent to the chessboard segmentation workflow in `ecognition` that I can apply on a large scale for multiple times. I'm not doing it in `ecognition` because I need to do large amounts of timesteps and large amounts of spatial area, and it's impractical in human-time-cost to do so for thousands of images.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on what 'chessboard segmentation' is?

Comment: Have you seen the scikit implementation: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#checkerboard-level-set

Comment: @Aaron I had not, thanks :)

Comment: @AlexLeith it's a segmentation that picks out pixel edges, essentially just chopping your image up by areas of a certain size. Ideally in this case grabbing pixel edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will extract each Landsat raster pixel as a polygon vector in `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` format. `input_data` represents the data in the input `xarray` dataset; you'll need to substitute in the dataset's geotransform and CRS data for `input_transform` and `input_crs`:

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio.features
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import shape

# Input array to segment and vectorise
input_array = np.random.rand(5, 5)
input_transform = (30, 0, 0, 0, -30, 0)  # replace with xarray transform
input_crs = 'EPSG:4326'  # replace with xarray CRS

plt.imshow(input_array)
```

**Example input:**

[image: Example input]

```
# Create array with a unique value per cell
unique_pixels = np.arange(input_array.size).reshape(input_array.shape)

# Vectorise each unique feature in array
vectors = rasterio.features.shapes(source=unique_pixels.astype(np.int16), 
                                     transform=input_transform)

# Extract polygons and values from generator
vectors = list(vectors)
values = [value for polygon, value in vectors]
polygons = [shape(polygon) for polygon, value in vectors]

# Create a geopandas dataframe populated with the polygon shapes
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={'id': values},
                       geometry=polygons,
                       crs=input_crs)

# Plot vectors by attribute
gdf.plot(column='id', edgecolor='black')
```

**Example output:**

[image: Example output]